# Create a function with an argument used in a formula

Tags: r

I'm a beginner at creating function and I have some trouble with something probably basic.

I'd like to create a function that takes as argument a data.frame and a name of a variable, and return the linear regression of this variable by the others (no real point with doing that, I'm just trying to learn how to create functions)

```
my_lm <- function(df, var) lm(var~., data = df)

my_lm(diamonds, price)
```

But I get this error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'price' not found"

Thanks for your help and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to pass `price` as `char`, and use `formula()` to convert a string in the proper object for the `lm`.

```
my_lm <- function(df, var) {
  f = formula(paste0(var, "~.")) # this creates "price ~ ." in the example
  lm(f, data = df)
}

my_lm(diamonds, var="price")
```

Or, if you have to pass `price` as "not a string", you need [NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html):

```
my_lm <- function(df, var) {
  var = substitute(var)
  f = formula(paste0(var, "~."))
  lm(f, data = df)
}

my_lm(diamonds, var=price)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works well. But is that possible to do that without having to quote the variable in the call ? I tried 
```
my_lm <- function(df, var) {
  var <- as.character(var)
  f = formula(paste0(var, "~.")) 
  lm(f, data = df)
}
``` 
But it didn't worked

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks again